# QEMU do not start when executed in background inside shell script

Tags: shell-script, qemu

I have an application that runs fine, with and without '&' when run directly from the terminal. However, if I try to execute it from a shell script, it works only if the trailing '&' is skipped. Thus, I am unable to start this process in background from inside the shell script.

```
<Path to My application> <options> &
```

The application window opens but makes no progress after that.

(The application is a modified(by me) version of qemu 0.13.0. When I run a disk image from that in background in a shell script, I get stuck with a black screen)

Comment: the application name would help

Comment: @aking Its a version of qemu modified by me.

Comment: okay, does stock qemu work?

Comment: @aking Yes, it does...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no need to background the application with the ampersand when it has a built-in option for doing so.  Such is the case with qemu (unless you've removed it):

```
% qemu-kvm --help | grep daemon
-daemonize      daemonize QEMU after initializing
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you see a message like

```
[1] suspended (tty output) myapplication
```

in the terminal? This message means that your program is trying to read from the terminal (probably because it's reading from its standard input). Since only a foreground program can read from the terminal, the program is suspended.

If you see this message, figure out why your program is reading. In desperation, try redirecting its standard input (`myapplication </dev/null`).

If you see no such message, it's some other bug in your program. Look at what your program is doing in a debugger or with `strace`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between running a backgrounded command from the terminal and from a shell script.

In a non-interactive shell (with job control disabled) the stdin of a backgrounded command gets implicitly redirected from `/dev/null`, which may cause your command not to execute at all.

See the POSIX standard on the [Shell Command Language: Asynchronous Lists](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_03_02).

```
# compare where fd 0 is pointing to
sh -c 'sleep 10 & lsof -p ${!}'
sh -c 'sleep 10 0<&0 & lsof -p ${!}'
sh -c 'set -m; sleep 10 & lsof -p ${!}'
sh -ic 'sleep 10 & lsof -p ${!}'
```